# Should I remove 3 nails in a palm tree

Tags: trees, palm

I have a palm tree with 3 nail holes that look like they haven't been there very long (new owner). Hence, I don't know how long the nails are but they are not totally embedded. Should I remove them and if so, how should I seal the holes?

Answer (score 1):

No need to remove them unless you are intending to use a chainsaw on the tree.  That becomes quite hazardous!

Trees compartmentalize damage so it is likely the tree has sealed off the area in contact with the nails.  If you do remove them do not seal the holes as this will cause more harm by creating an area where moisture can cause rot.

You can read about Alex Shigo and his research [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alex_Shigo#Research).  They did research on  how trees deal with damage.

Comment: should i hammer them in more, I don't want the tree pertruding around the nails

Comment: @kpeterson if you hammer them in then the tree is damaged more.  In the big scheme of things the damage is probably not significant.